# Converting unix script to windows script - emulating a Sed command in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have a unix script (korn to be exact) that is working well and I need to convert it windows batch script. So far I have tried inserting a powershell command line on my code, but it doesn't work. Please help, I am just new to both unix scripting and windows scripting so any help will do.

This is the line of code that I need to convert:

```
#create new file to parse ; exclude past instances of timestamp
    parsefile=/tmp/$$.parse
    sed -e "1,/$TIMESTAMP/d" -e "/$TIMESTAMP/d" $DSTLOGFILE > $parsefile
```

So far I have tried a powershell command line to be called on my script but it didn't work:

```
:set_parse_file
@powershell -Command "Get-Content $SCHLOGFILE | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace('1,/"$TIMESTAMP"/d' '/"$TIMESTAMP"/d'} | Set-Content $PARSEFILE"
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: You should [edit] your question to contain text to be replaced and also your expected outcome. Read `Get-Help about_comparison_operators` for the syntax of the RegEx based `-replace` operator.

Comment: 'It didn't work, any suggestions please' isn't a properly formed question, also we aren't a code conversion, tutorial or interactive reference service. You say that you are new to scripting, so my advice is that you learn it yourself through trial and error. Once you have a specific explainable and replicable issue with your code, we will try to help you with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PowerShell has *no* `sed`-like constructs for processing *ranges* of lines** (e.g., `sed` interprets `1,/foo/` as referring to the range of consecutive lines from line 1 through a subsequent line that matches *regex* `foo`)

Emulating this feature with **line-by-line processing would be much more verbose**, but a **comparatively more concise version is possible if the input file is processed *as a whole*** - which is only an option with files small enough to fit into memory as a whole, however (PSv5+ syntax).

Here's the pure PowerShell code:

```
$escapedTimeStamp = [regex]::Escape($TIMESTAMP)
(Get-Content -Raw $SCHLOGFILE) -replace ('(?ms)\A.*?\r?\n.*?' + $escapedTimeStamp + '.*?\r?\n') `
                               -replace ('(?m)^.*?' + $escapedTimeStamp + '.*\r?\n') |
  Set-Content -NoNewline $PARSEFILE
```

Note that `[regex]::Escape()` is used to make sure that the value of `$TIMESTAMP` is treated as a *literal*, even if it happens to contain regex metacharacters (chars. with special meaning to the regex engine).
Your `ksh` code doesn't do that (and it's nontrivial to do in `ksh`), so if - conversely - `$TIMESTAMP` *should* be interpreted as a regex, simply omit that step and use `$TIMESTAMP` directly.

The `-replace` operator is regex-based and uses the .NET regular-expression engine.

It is the use of `Get-Content`'s `-Raw`  switch that requires PSv3+ and the use of `Set-Content`'s `-NoNewline` switch that requires PSv5+. You can make this command work in earlier versions, but it requires more effort.

**Calling the above from `cmd.exe` (a batch file) gets quite unwieldy** - and you always have to be wary of quoting issues - but it should work:

```
@powershell.exe -noprofile -command "$escapedTimeStamp = [regex]::Escape('%TIMESTAMP%'); (Get-Content -Raw '%SCHLOGFILE%') -replace ('(?ms)\A.*?\r?\n.*?' + $escapedTimeStamp + '.*?\r?\n') -replace ('(?m)^.*?' + $escapedTimeStamp + '.*\r?\n') | Set-Content -NoNewline '%PARSEFILE%'"
```

Note how the `-command` argument is passed as a single `"..."` string, which is ultimately the safest and conceptually cleanest way to pass code to PowerShell.
Also note the need to embed *batch* variables as `%varname%` in the command, and since they are enclosed in embedded `'...'` above, the assumption is that their values contain no `'` chars.

Therefore, **consider implementing your entire script *in Powershell*** - you'll have a much more powerful scripting language at your disposal, and you'll avoid the quoting headaches that come from bridging two disparate worlds.